# why does quantumn theory not reconcile itself with general relativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

Why has there not been a resolution in the gravitational effect between the two?
It seems that quantum theory and Einstein disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Physical theories contain parameters whose values must be empirically determined to make predictions. (For example, for electromagnetism you need the fine structure constant.) We therefore need the theory to have only finitely many parameters. For a quantum field theory, this requires a property called [renormalisability](http://en,wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalisation). As explained [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.3555v2.pdf), a renormalisable quantum field theory's high-energy spectrum doesn't behave the same way as gravity's, so a quantum field theory of gravity can't be renormalised.